# How to serialize object without quoting arrays and records in json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

When serializing my object with Newtonsoft's Json.net I get:

```
{"status":"1",
 "message":"test",
 "records":"[{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"file1\"},
             {\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"file2\"},
             {\"id\":\"3\", \"name\":\"file3\"}]" // I want to get rid of the extra quotes for the array
 }
```

I want to have:

```
{"status":"1",
 "message":"test",
 "records":[{"id":"1", "name":"file1"},
             {"id":"2", "name":"file2"},
             {"id":"3", "name":"file3"}] // NOTE: this is an Array of records
}
```

This is the simplified code I use to serialize:

```
 QHttpResponse tempResponse = new QHttpResponse() { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Message = "File found." };
                JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(tempResponse);
                jo.Add("records",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo));
```

This is the QHttpResponse class:

```
  public class QHttpResponse
{

    #region Feilds
    /// <summary>
    /// Status code of the http response (e.g.:400 = bad request.)
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("status_code")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Message (Content) of the response.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: checkout this [JSONLint site](http://jsonlint.com/) here you an validate valid or invalid json sting

Comment: It looks like you have a small typo of adding `jo` to `jo`

Comment: @ohmusama: Yeah, I got hung up on that too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
jo.Add("records",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo));
```

You serialize the array adding it to the "records" property, then you serialized the whole thing thus you get a double serialization, which is why you have the escaped \".

try:

```
jo["records"] = arrayData;
```

Then later when you serialize this should come out as you expect.